# Endlessly stuck in SSH login loop?

Tags: ssh

I've got a weird issue. Every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or use `logout` or `exit`, I see

```
Connection to remote.host.com closed
```

and then I am immediately logged back in:

```
Last login: Thu Oct 6 21:04:20 2011 from xyz
user@remote.host.com ~ $
```

Why is this happening and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Give some details about your setup. At least the system and command with which you connect. If it is just `ssh user@hostname`, then what is the output of `type ssh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the option that says "re-connect if disconnected" in your SSH client. If you're using the command-line client, check to see if it's not running something like `function ssh() { while true; ssh "$@"; done; }`

Comment: That was it. I forgot about the loop I wrote since I was initially having connection issues.